# How to scroll to the next section/div (of choice) when a button is clicked using only Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have been learning Js for the last few months and I took it upon myself to not learn any Jquery until I'm very comfortable with pure js.

**I want something that has the exact same effect of [This code here](http://jsfiddle.net/shlomohassid/6r1h687k/) without using Jquery.**  Please include comments for explanation if possible

```
// --------- Jquery ---------


$(function(){

var pagePositon = 0,
    sectionsSeclector = 'section',
    $scrollItems = $(sectionsSeclector),
    offsetTolorence = 30,
    pageMaxPosition = $scrollItems.length - 1;

//Map the sections:
$scrollItems.each(function(index,ele) { $(ele).attr("debog",index).data("pos",index); });

// Bind to scroll
$(window).bind('scroll',upPos);

//Move on click:
$('#arrow a').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('next') && pagePositon+1 <= pageMaxPosition) {
        pagePositon++;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
              scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
        }, 300);
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('previous') && pagePositon-1 >= 0) {
        pagePositon--;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
              scrollTop: $scrollItems.eq(pagePositon).offset().top
          }, 300);
        return false;
    }
});

//Update position func:
function upPos(){
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
   var $cur = null;
    $scrollItems.each(function(index,ele){
        if ($(ele).offset().top < fromTop + offsetTolorence) $cur = $(ele);
    });
   if ($cur != null && pagePositon != $cur.data('pos')) {
       pagePositon = $cur.data('pos');
   }                   
}

});
```

Comment: Have you considered using [fullPgae.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) for that? There's a [pure Javascript version of it](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/pure%20javascript%20(Alpha)) which provides that functionality plus many other useful things such as callbacks, browsers compatibility, browser support etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

> *"This works great unless I manually scroll to a different div using the mouse then try to hit the next/prev button. any solution for that? Thank you"*

Each `<section>` is dynamically given a `data-id` attribute with a value corresponding to its index. If a `<section>` is clicked, then it becomes the current active `<section>` so when the arrows are clicked, the scrolling will start from there.

**Specific parts of Demo has been commented as "UPDATED"**

---

There's a perfect method called **[`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)**

```
  x.scrollIntoView({ 
     behavior: 'smooth' 
  });
```

It has jQuery-like options built in.

**Details commented in Demo**

#### Demo

```js
// Reference counter outside of function
var idx = 0;
// Collect all sections in a NodeList
var sxn = document.querySelectorAll('section');
// UPDATED
/* Loop through the NodeList sxn
|| Assign a data-id attribute to each section 
|| Set data-id value to current index of each
|| section
*/
for (let i = 0; i < sxn.length; i++) {
  sxn[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
}
// Reference nav
var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
// Collect all anchors into a HTMLCollection
var lnx = document.links;
// UPDATED
// Register document on click event callback is move()
document.addEventListener('click', move, false);
// UPDATED
/* move() determines the direction of scroll by idx
|| If a section is clicked instead of the arrows,
|| then the data-id value of said section is now idx.
|| So when a section is clicked, nothing happens until an 
|| arrow is clicked. Once that happens, scrolling starts
|| from the last section clicked.
*/
function move(e) {
  if (e.target == lnx[0]) {
    idx--;
    if (idx < 0) {
      idx = sxn.length - 1;
    }
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'SECTION') {
    idx = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
  } else {
    idx++;
    if (idx > sxn.length - 1) {
      idx = 0;
    }
  }
  return idxScroll(idx);
}

// Pass idx thru idxScroll
function idxScroll(idx) {
  // Reference current active section
  var act = document.querySelector('.active');
  // Determine which section becomes active
  var x = sxn[idx];
  // Remove active class from current section
  act.classList.remove('active');
  // Add active class to new section
  x.classList.add('active');
  /* scrollIntoView method has a behavior option that animates
  || scrolling
  */
  x.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0
}

a {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <a href='#/'>◀</a>
    <a href='#/'>▶</a>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <section style='background:red' class='active'></section>

    <section style='background:blue'></section>

    <section style='background:yellow'></section>

    <section style='background:black'></section>

    <section style='background:green'></section>

    <section style='background:purple'></section>

    <section style='background:deeppink'></section>

    <section style='background:cyan'></section>

    <section style='background:tomato'></section>

    <section style='background:brown'></section>

    <section style='background:orchid'></section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This works great unless I manually scroll to a different div using the mouse then try to hit the next/prev button. any solution for that? Thank you

Comment: @TarekDemachkie It will now begin its scrolling from the last section clicked. So if you scroll down 2 sections manually, then click the section you are in (3rd section), it will start its scrolling from the 3rd section once you give it a direction by clicking the arrows. See update

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var secs = document.querySelectorAll('section');
var currentSection = 0;
document.querySelector('#arrow').addEventListener('click', move);

function move(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('next') && currentSection < secs.length) {
    window.scroll({
      top: secs[++currentSection].offsetTop,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    //    secs[++currentSection].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  } else if (currentSection > 0) {
    window.scroll({
      top: secs[--currentSection].offsetTop,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });

  }
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6r1h687k/168/) solution. I used the smoothscroll API polyfill. For the animations incase your browser doesn't support the API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior).

Comment: This is only working if I use the buttons only. when scrolling manually with the mouse and then using the button it doesn't work. any solution for that?

Comment: Yes...make the scroll target the actual element rather than the window. Let me edit the fiddle and you'll see.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6r1h687k/183/ this gets you started. Notice how I've simplified the code. There are other improvements to make

Comment: It is still having problems when manually scrolling. try to scroll first with your mouse to the next colored box and then hit next to see what I'm talking about. Thank you for your effort